# Direct I/O in Python with O_DIRECT

Tags: python

I am new to python and for some project, I have to use python for some I/O. I started with a simple python code that uses open() method from os module and the code worked fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, mmap

# Open a file
fd = os.open( "foo.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)
s = ' ' * 1024
# Write one string
os.write(fd, s)
# Close opened file
os.close( fd )
```

Now, since I want to use direct I/O, I want to use O_DIRECT flag with open() to bypass all (or some) effects of cache. Unfortunately, if I open a file with O_DIRECT and subsequently, try to write to that file, there is a strange error message:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Now, as suggested in this [article](http://www.alexonlinux.com/direct-io-in-python): I have to use mmap to map portion of file into memory. Mmap works with granularity of one memory page – 4kb that is. So every memory mapped buffer is naturally memory aligned to 4kb, thus to 512 byte boundary too. The code with mmap is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys, mmap

# Open a file
fd = os.open( "foo.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT|os.O_DIRECT)
m = mmap.mmap(-1, 1024)
s = ' ' * 1024
m.write(s)
# Write one string
os.write(fd, m)
# Close opened file
os.close( fd )
```

My questions are:

1. In line m = mmap.mmap(-1, 1024), I understand specifying -1 as file descriptor allocates RAM. What is the significance of 1024?
2. What s = ' ' * 1024 does? Again, what is the significance of 1024 here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In line `m = mmap.mmap(-1, 1024)`, I understand specifying -1 as file descriptor allocates RAM. What is the significance of 1024?

Via the docs:

> [`class mmap.mmap(fileno, length, flags=MAP_SHARED, prot=PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, access=ACCESS_DEFAULT[, offset])`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap)

It's the length of the mapped region. Also, you're correct in the significance of `-1`: "To map anonymous memory, -1 should be passed as the fileno along with the length."

> What `s = ' ' * 1024` does? Again, what is the significance of 1024 here?

Creates a string of 1024 spaces. 1024 is the length of the mapped region; the data you're writing. (It should, though, preferably be `b' ' * 1024` to create a bytestring of 1024 0x20 bytes. An arbitrary text string might not get encoded into exactly 1024 bytes.)