# How can I do an unbuffered disk read in Python?

Tags: python, linux, disk-io

I need to read a sector from the physical disk, but without using the system cache.

I tried this:

```
import os

disk_path = "/dev/sdc"

try:
    disk_fd = os.open(disk_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_DIRECT)
    os.lseek(disk_fd, 12345 * 4096, os.SEEK_SET)
    buffer = os.read(disk_fd, 4096)

finally:
    if disk_fd: os.close(disk_fd)
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marus/direct.py", line 8, in <module>
    buffer = os.read(disk_fd, 4096)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

In Windows I know that there are some alignment requirements for unbuffered file reading, but here in Linux I don't know how it is... What can be wrong here ? I executed the script as `sudo`.

Edit:
If I remove the `os.O_DIRECT` flag, everything works fine...

**Update:**
I preallocated an aligned buffer like this:

```
buffer_address = ctypes.create_string_buffer(buffer_size + sector_size)
buffer_offset = (ctypes.addressof(buffer_address) + sector_size - 1) & ~(sector_size - 1)
buffer = ctypes.string_at(buffer_offset, buffer_size)
```

...but now how can I use this buffer with `os.read()` ?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, I'm curious what is your use case? I can imagine the need for unbuffered write, but not for the read

Comment: From the manpage: `Under Linux 2.4, transfer sizes, the alignment of the user buffer, and the file offset must all be multiples of the logical block size of the filesystem.  Since Linux 2.6.0, alignment to the logical block size of the underlying storage (typically 512 bytes) suffices. The logical block size can be determined using the ioctl(2) BLKSSZGET operation or from the shell using the command: blockdev --getss` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html#NOTES

Comment: @Marat I need to keep the disk active, like not entering the standby state.
NickODell but I seeked to multiples of the sector size and I also read a multiple buffer size

Comment: Further down in the manpage: "Some filesystems may not implement the flag, in which case open() fails with the error EINVAL if it is used."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man 2 open:

```
   Since Linux 2.6.0, alignment to the logical block size of the  un‐
   derlying  storage  (typically  512 bytes) suffices
```

man 2 read:

```
   EINVAL fd  is  attached  to  an object which is unsuitable for reading; or the file was opened with the O_DIRECT
          flag, and either the address specified in buf, the value specified in count, or the file  offset  is  not
          suitably aligned.
```

E.g. *both* file position and buffer in memory should be aligned at 512 bytes. You can control file position with lseek, but read buffer in python requires different approach.

See https://bugs.python.org/issue5396 for the details and remedy.

Here's another discussion: [Direct I/O in Python with O_DIRECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674456/direct-i-o-in-python-with-o-direct)

Here what works for me:

```
import os
import mmap

disk_path = "/dev/sdc"

disk_fd=None
try:
    disk_fd = os.open(disk_path, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_DIRECT)
    os.lseek(disk_fd, 12345 * 4096, os.SEEK_SET)
    f=os.fdopen(disk_fd, 'rb+', 0)
    m=mmap.mmap(-1, 4096)
    f.readinto(m)
    print(m.read(4096))
finally:
    if disk_fd: os.close(disk_fd)
```

the code above for me prints contents of that block.

This is how it works:

```
    m=mmap.mmap(-1, 4096)
```

this allocates 4k of memory using `mmap`. Returned memory will be aligned at memory page start, which again is usually 4k.

`os.read` cannot read to a buffer. So here they are using the following trick - create a file object from the os file descriptor:

```
    f=os.fdopen(disk_fd, 'rb+', 0)
```

the above creates `f` which is similar to what you get from normal `open` - it will have read/write/close.

Them they call

```
    f.readinto(m)
```

which allows them to read from file object into a pre-allocated block of memory.

Now is the final step is to extract the data from mmaped memory block:

```
    print(m.read(4096))
```

Comment: As you cand see, the seek and the buffer size in my example are multiple of 4096 (my physical disk sector size). The only one variable that remains unsure is the addres of the buffer. But that is controled by the `os.read()` function... Or not ? Cand I preallocate the buffer to an 4096 bytes alignment ?

Comment: You buffer should _aligned_, e.g. _start_ from a position which is multiple of 512. Size matters too of course.

Comment: I alligned the buffer too (see my update), but I cannot used with os.read()...

Comment: Python issue5396 gives recommendation on how to do that using _mmap_.

Comment: there is readinto: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.readinto

Comment: Solution from issue5396  works for me to read a block device. Why are you hesitant to use it?

Comment: I want to use it, but I am new to linux and python and I don't fully understand what that page says...

Comment: I updated my answer with the details.

Comment: Great ! It really works ! So we map only 4096 bytes of the disk, at the seeked position, not the entire size ? Do you think that this a reliable method of doing unbuffered disk read ? Because I read in that page someone said: "However, based on this issue, I'm a little concerned this won't be fully supported by python going forward; so use with care."

Comment: I need to ask you something verry important here. At the end, if I try to `.close()` both the `f` and the `disk_fd` I get "[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" It's ok to close just one of them, as `f` object is just a wraper for the file descriptor ? And if so, which one, the file object or the descriptor handle ? And maped file shouln't be closed too ?

Comment: Yes, just close the file object - e.g. `f`. It will also close the underlying handle.